# web2py - remove blank option from IS_IN_DB validator

Tags: validation, web2py

In web2py, say I have modified the default auth_user table by adding a field called 'agent_code'. This field should include values from another table:

```
auth_table = db.define_table(
    auth.settings.table_user_name,
    Field('first_name', length=128, default=''),
        ...more fields here...,
    Field('auth_age_cod', length=512,default=None))

auth_table.auth_age_cod.requires = \
    IS_IN_DB(db, db.agea.agea_cod,
             '%(agea_cod)s - %(agea_name)s',
             error_message='Agent not in DB')
```

I want users to be able to identify themselves as agents during registration.

The user registration form now shows the dropbox to allow for agent selection, but includes a blank option at the start. For some reasons this is not acceptable in our system.

After investigating the source code for the validator, I found that the IS_IN_DB validator has a parameter called 'zero'. This is by default set to '' (empty string) and creates a blank option in the droplist.

So, to remove the blank option, change the validator to:

```
IS_IN_DB(db, db.agea.agea_cod,
         '%(agea_cod)s - %(agea_name)s',
         error_message='Agent not in DB',
         zero=None)
```

Comment: It looks like your asking and answering your own question which is fine but you should submit your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear, but if you are asking if the `zero` argument in `IS_IN_DB` is for that purposes, it is. The [web2py manual](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07) says that the argument `zero` in `IS_IN_DB` works like `zero` in `IS_IN_SET`

And for `IS_IN_SET` the manual states: *The `zero` argument is optional and it determines the text of the option selected by default, an option which is not accepted by the `IS_IN_SET` validator itself. If you do not want a "choose one" option, set `zero=None`*